# Word to describe the Operating System size?

Tags: windows

I want to have an enum that describes the "width" of the Operating System.

The Values will be OS32 or OS64, but what is a good name for the enum its self?

```
enum OS_SIZE
{
   OS32,
   OS64
}
```

The best I can come up with is "OS Size", or maybe "OS Word Size" but I don't really like these.  Is there a term in the industry that is used to describe the underlying word width of the operating system?

Comment: The only OS size I know is 'big'.

Comment: What "word size" are you talking about? The size of an int? The size of a long? The size of a pointer?

Comment: Anon, as you imply, "word size" doesn't describe the concept. I used that term to help convey my question. As you can see from the answers posted so far, there isn't an obvious term to even describe what I am trying to ask, but you all know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 4):

- `Bitness`
- `PointerSize`
- `WordLength`.

Comment: A word is two octects in size = 16 bits.

Comment: @vz0: No, it's not.  A word is the natural unit of memory (not the indivisible unit) for any given processor.  Microsoft defines a `WORD` typedef in the Windows headers, but it hasn't actually been word-sized since Win16.

Answer (score 1):

WMI calls it `AddressWidth`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the size of the OS, but the number of bits of a main memory address: 32 bits vs. 64 bits, which is also the size of a pointer.

Either case, the main difference is from a hardware architecture point of view, so I'd say "Number of Bits in Architecture Address", NoBiAA, or just "`ARCH_ADDR_SIZE`".

Answer (score 0):

`OSWordSize` and `OSWordBitSize` both work for me.